# Searching an elasticsearch index with NEST yields no results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm playing around with NEST, and I'm adding stuff to the ES index without any problems. Getting any results back is another matter, however.

Here's the output in my browser for `/nest-testing/_search/?pretty`

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "nest-testing",
      "_type" : "plain_text",
      "_id" : "\\\\domain.net\\path\\to\\lorem.txt",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
  "id": "\\\\domain.net\\path\\to\\lorem.txt",
  "full_unc_path": "\\\\domain.net\\path\\to\\lorem.txt",
  "file_name": "lorem.txt",
  "parent_directory": "\\\\domain.net\\path\\to\\lorem",
  "date_created": "2014-01-28T15:47:30.4302806Z",
  "date_modified": "2014-01-29T15:47:30.4302806Z",
  "fulltext": "Also, I like spaghetti and Meatballs.",
  "original_filesize": 37,
  "extracted_text_size": 37
}
    } ]
  }
}
```

Here's my NEST call:

```
var result = client.Search(s => s
    .Index(TEST_INDEX)
    .MatchAll()
);
```

I get an empty collection back when I run it. (QueryString searches don't work, either.) Making the query less specific ( `.AllIndices()` ) doesn't change the result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not explicitly saying what the return type should be `NEST` will assume `Search<dynamic>`

If you do so you need to explicitly tell it which index or type you want to search through at or `.AllIndices()` and/or `.AllTypes()`

Comment: I put together a second index using the Twitter example that elasticsearch.org has, and using `.AllIndices().AllTypes()` returns the three documents I added to the `twitter` index. There are none returned from the `nest-testing` index. Looking at the structure of the nest-testing JSON, I think I might be creating the index incorrectly. (Everything is stuffed inside `_source`--which is not what I want--so I think I might be doing something wrong further upstream.)