# ElasticSearch and NEST Query Issue

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

**SOLVED**:
The URI was incorrect. Was "h||p://#.#.#.#/:9200" and should have been "h||p://#.#.#.#:9200". This was causing the API to change the port number to 80. Surprised the API actually was able to connect to ElasticSearch instance with the incorrect port number.

I'm new to NEST and ElasticSearch and trying to put together a a simple MatchAll query in NEST.

When I perform a MatchAll from Sense

```
POST /movies/movie/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I get all the movie objects in the movies index.

But when I try the NEST query

```
var result = client.Search(s => s.Type("movie").MatchAll());
```

I get nothing back. Tried setting the return type to a movie class, and still no results.

```
    public class Movie
   {
      public string title { get; set; }
      public string director { get; set; }
      public int year { get; set; }
      public List<string> genres { get; set; }
   }
```

Also tried .AllIndices() and/or .AllTypes() per this reply
[Searching an elasticsearch index with NEST yields no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436186/searching-an-elasticsearch-index-with-nest-yields-no-results)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Heres the connection string setting the default index.

```
ConnectionSettings connection = new ConnectionSettings(uri).UsePrettyResponses().SetDefaultIndex("movies");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for `IsValid` on `result` to see if the call succeeded or not.

`result.ConnectionStatus` will hold all the information you need to determine what went wrong.

If you'd like to throw exceptions instead you can enable that by calling:

```
.SetConnectionStatusHandler(c=> { 
    if (!c.Success)
        throw new Exception(c.ToString());
})
```

on your `ConnectionSettings`

Calling ToString on an `ConnectionStatus` object prints all the request and response details in human readable form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martijn.

Intersting that the IsValid() method is actually in an IQueryResponse object, and not the ElasticClient like the documentation states.


http://nest.azurewebsites.net/concepts/connecting.html